# Weird signed comparison results

Tags: vhdl, signed

I encountered an unexpected comparison result when comparing a 2bit `std_logic_vector` with `std_logic_signed` package loaded to hex constants such as `x"3"`. I was expecting the comparison to be true when both bits are set but it's always false. Probably because the `std_logic_vector` gets sign extended to 4bit for the comparison against the 4bit hex constant. What's really weird though, is that the comparison works as expected when using the constant `3`, but only when using a `std_logic_vector`, not when using a `signed` type. See sample code below. All asserts fail except the first one. Why does this assert succeed? Also when not loading the `std_logic_signed` package the `vec0 = x"3"` comparison still fails. Only when loading `std_logic_unsigned` makes this comparison succeed.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture bhv of tb is
    signal vec0 : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal vec1 : signed(1 downto 0)           := (others => '1');
begin
    process
    begin
        assert vec0 = 3     report "Test 1";
        assert vec0 = x"3"  report "Test 2";
        assert vec1 = 3     report "Test 3";
        assert vec1 = x"3"  report "Test 4";
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 1):

When compares are done using signed/unsigned, both operands are expanded to the length of the longest operand and then compared.

So, for the x"3" case, you have a 4 bit number "0011" = +3

vec0 and vec1 = "11" = -1. Because they are SLV treated as a signed, or an actual signed, they are sign extended to "1111". Hence "1111" is not equal to "0011".

When comparing signed/slv to integer, the integer is converted to a vector the length of the other operand. In both cases, literal 3 cannot be converted to a 2 bit signed (as the range is -2 to +1)

For std_logic_signed (a non-standard VHDL package) the 3 is converted to "11" by the nature of how the function works. Hence you get a match (incorrectly)

Numeric_std has a check function where integers outside of the range of the signed (or unsigned) operand automatically return false.

numeric_std IS a VHDL standard.

Moral - dont bother using std_logic_signed.